# Using visualstudio.com Team Services build failure, 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure-devops

First time trying to use this to manage a project.  It seems like it has potential, until now.  My project builds just fine on my machine, but on the Team Services server it won't build, I get a few errors:

First error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

This second one is a warning, not an error,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2041,5): 
Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly 
"Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". 
Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. 
If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

and another error:

```
The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can anyone help explain why I'm getting these errors, and how I can fix them?

Comment: Are you using a NuGet package restore task?

Comment: Yes. I've given up. Can't figure it out and there's no help on here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent? What's .net framework version of your project? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: I rebuilt the project from scratch.  I have a web project, and 3 class libraries, DataModel, Services, and Utility.  The build problem is now with the Utility project, "Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "log4net".".  Doesn't make any sense, it's there in the packages folder, and I checked it in.  I'm using Hosted agent, rebuilt the project and could recreate the above error, just the log4net one. But it seems similar, problems with references.  I'm probably doing something really stupid, I'm new to VSTS. LOGFILE: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmmTZIvbm0oyifEj9xRRxaaBfWU_Tg

Comment: Using .net framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the log, you added the package folder and files to the source control, but exclude the dll files (e.g. log4net.dll).

Also, you just added **NuGet Tool Installer** task to build definition, which is used to download specific NuGet tool and adds it to the Path variable, it won’t restore the packages during the build.

So, refer to these steps below to deal with this issue:

1. Delete package folder from source control
2. Add **NuGet** task to build definition and specify solution path.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try this later and get back to you on my success, or lack thereof.

Comment: Hi, tried what you said.  I deleted the project and set it all up again from scratch, without adding the packages folder.  I have Nuget Task on build definition, and I have specified the solution path.  I'm losing all hope here.  Similar error with packages, this time the problem is with Ninject packages - but from looking at the log, it seems like they are restored and added to the packages folder.  I don't get it.  Here's the log file if you want to take another look https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmmTZIvbm0oyifEj9xRRxaaBfWU_Tg but whether you do or not, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Right, so I removed NinjectWeb.cs, and all of the Ninject references, and it built successfully!  But it's pointless, this project will now not run without ninject.  I will get parameterless constructor error on controllers (I'm using repository pattern and unit of work).  One step forward, two steps back.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get parameterless constructor error, I get null reference error when I try to access my Services.

Comment: @ailinmcc666 Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share the simple project on the OneDrive.

Comment: I got it fixed.  I removed the packages, then removed Ninject and reinstalled.  I think it was issues incompatible ninject packages.  Thanks.